# Spacing rows in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I am having a very difficult time typesetting this Cayley table.  When I use this code, it gives me an error and tells me that I am using an illegal unit of measure.  I know I do not have the correct spacing but I do not know how to fix it.  I would greatly appreciate any help! Here is my code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}

$\cdot$ & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5]\\
\hline
  [1] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] \\
  [2] & [2] & [4] & [0] & [2] & [4] \\
  [3] & [3] & [0] & [3] & [0] & [3] \\
  [4] & [4] & [2] & [0] & [4] & [2] \\
  [5] & [5] & [4] & [3] & [2] & [1] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Answer (score 6):

You should change yor file for example in the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cccccc}
%
$\cdot$ & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5]\\
\hline
{}  [1] & [1] & [2] & [3] & [4] & [5] \\
 {} [2] & [2] & [4] & [0] & [2] & [4] \\
 {} [3] & [3] & [0] & [3] & [0] & [3] \\
 {} [4] & [4] & [2] & [0] & [4] & [2] \\
 {} [5] & [5] & [4] & [3] & [2] & [1] \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Explanation. `\\` has an optional argument: an additional length. Hence `\\[2]` is interpreted as a try of usage of this length. For example `\\[2mm]` means additional 2 milimeters of vertical space.

[image]